# Building a Multi-Tenant App with Dialog Flow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to build a multi-tenant app with Dialogflow? We have a lot of customers who all would benefit from their own Dialogflow integration. For example, we do scheduling for our customers, would it be possible for each of our customers to have their own bot that we configure on Dialogflow?

I am not seeing any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have separate chatbots I will export my dialogflow agent as zip and will import it in separate project for different customer base.

The export/import option can be found in Settings > Import and export tab